# mysql: unable to use mysqldump on production

Tags: mysql

I tried below commands,

```
mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u username -p db_name > dumpfile.sql;
mysqldump -u username -p password db_name > dumpfile.sql;
mysqldump db_name > dumpfile.sql;
```

It always throw this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump ..' at line 1

mysql version: 5.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while taking backup with mysqldump in mysql command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575356/error-while-taking-backup-with-mysqldump-in-mysql-command-line)

Comment: have you tried using the full path to the mysqldump command? Might be an issue with your PATH vars

Answer (score 0):

You should launch this command from CLI as it's a separate binary executable. According to the message you get you trying to execute it as SQL command and it's totally incorrect.